# Simple explanation about how to create Relationships with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongo db/Mongoose, this question is about mongoose and relationships between collections, I know there's a lot of tutorials about how to make this work but still not able to understand an easy way to make this work. I have a two models:

This is the main model:

```
       'use strict';

        var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
            Schema = mongoose.Schema;

                var CategorySchema = new Schema({
                    name    : String,
                    info    : String,
                    items   : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
                });

                var itemsSchema = Schema({
                    name        : String,
                    description : String,
                    price       : Number
                });


        var Item  = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);

        module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

I need to populate items array inside category collection and create the relationship between the two collections.

When I a post from postman I can see the items array getting created but I am not able to populate the array.

If I do get categories, this is the response:

```
  [
        {
          "_id": "564120be4123198a1f93feb5",
          "name": "Classic",
          "info": "this is the info",
          "__v": 0,
          "items": []
        },
        {
          "_id": "5641220b02968e901f678ff5",
          "name": "Classic",
          "info": "this is the info",
          "__v": 0,
          "items": []
        }
      ]
```

This is the put result to api/categories/

```
     {
        "_id": "564120be4123198a1f93feb5",
        "name": "test again",
        "info": "this is the info",
        "__v": 1,
        "items": []
      }
```

Desired output:

```
      {
        "_id": "564120be4123198a1f93feb5",
        "name": "test again",
        "info": "this is the info",
        "__v": 1,
        "items": [
          {
            "_id": "some id"
            "name": "name",
            "description": "lorem ipsup"
          },
          {
            "_id": "some id"
            "name": "name",
            "description": "lorem ipsup"
          },
          {
            "_id": "some id"
            "name": "name",
            "description": "lorem ipsup"
          },
        ]
      }
```

Comment: What logic did you use to insert an item into the category?

Comment: @KevinB I need to have the ability of removing individual items in the future.

Comment: What logic did you use to insert an item into the category? If it worked correctly, you should see an id in that array. I don't see any ids.

Comment: @KevinB I am not able to get any ids inside the array. I am following the following documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: *"I am not able to get any ids inside the array"* that's what i'm trying to point out. .populate won't populate anything if there's nothing in the array for it to populate! currently it is empty, so .populate won't change that. For .populate to work the array would need to contain item ids that belong to that category.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you've a reference in Category, you should use `populate` method to inform mongoose that you want him to retrieve the referenced items.

Something like:

```js
var Category = require('./category.model'); 
Category.find().populate("items");
```

if you want to populate only one field of item model you can add it ine parameter of populate:

```js
Category.find().populate("items","name");
```

I don't know what you want to achieve but it seems to me that the other way could be more beneficial (having a reference to category into item model).